# Verifying delivery of TCP messages

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm writing an application to send syslogs to a central server. The network connection to the server is expected to be unreliable. For this reason, I need to be able to check whether the messages have been received by the server, so that if the send is unsuccessful I can try sending them again later.

I have no control over the server, only the ability to form a TCP connection with it - most questions I've seen recommend writing custom ACK logic, but that's not an option for me. I need an entirely client-side approach. Is there any way I can access the TCP acknowledgements in order to mark a message as sent?

Comment: It is my understanding that you'll get an error if the send fails (i.e. if data does not reach the server). What the server does to the data after it's received (whether it's guaranteed to be stored, or whatever) is a different matter, of course.

Comment: As I don't control the server, what the server does with the data is not my problem! I just need to make sure it gets there OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other poster has mentioned, TCP is a reliable protocol. You can wrap this in some exception handling code to ensure that messages are re-sent when the connection is restored, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace TCPClientTest
{
    class SyslogMessage
    {
        public Guid Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        public byte[] MessageData;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static readonly int TCP_PORT = 1337;

        static byte[] SendTCPMessage(String hostname, int port, byte[] data)
        {
            using (var client = new TcpClient(hostname, port))
            {
                using (var stream = client.GetStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    var responseData = new byte[1024];

                    var byteCount = stream.Read(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
                    return responseData.Take(byteCount).ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        static void SendSyslog(String hostname, int port, SyslogMessage m)
        {
            SendTCPMessage(hostname, port, m.MessageData);
        }

        static Queue<SyslogMessage> sysLogQueue = new Queue<SyslogMessage>(new List<SyslogMessage>()
        { 
            new SyslogMessage() { MessageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test data 1")},
            new SyslogMessage() { MessageData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test data 2")}
        });

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(SendLogs, null, 1000, 5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Press return to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void SendLogs(object state)
        {
            while (sysLogQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    var m = sysLogQueue.Peek();
                    SendSyslog("localhost", TCP_PORT, m);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent sys log: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.MessageData));
                    // Remove from queue.
                    sysLogQueue.Dequeue();
                }
                catch (SocketException e)
                {
                    // Leave in the queue.
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to send log: Socket exception occurred: {0}", e);
                    // Break until next attempt.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've used port 1337 for this, just set this to whatever you need.

Answer (score 2):

The TCP protocol guarantees that the data is properly delivered at the remote server. To quote from the original TCP specification in [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

> An acknowledgment by TCP does not guarantee that the data has been
> delivered to the end user, but only that the receiving TCP has taken
> the responsibility to do so.

So if you do not get an error from your sending part, you have a confirm that the remove server TCP stack has properly received your data. TCP has built-in detection for damaged, lost, duplicated, or out of order delivered packets (using sequence numbers) and will retransmit packets when it detects problems.